# Expand into 1-minute, calculate average

Tags: r, time, data.table, time-series, dplyr

I am trying to manipulate time in order to redistribute average idle time on a **per minute basis**:

```
#############################################################
##Reproducible example 1 (n=10):
#############################################################    df.in <- structure(list(id = c(31, 46, 60, 57, 44, 04, 18, 55, 
22, 5), loc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), t.arrive = structure(c(1425197374, 
1425197392, 1425197411, 1425198171, 1425198190, 1425196800, 1425197837, 
1425198027, 1425197507, 1425198026), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), t.leave = structure(c(1425197409, 1425197531, 
1425197555, 1425198171, 1425198296, 1425196992, 1425197865, 1425198028, 
1425197512, 1425198026), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    idle = c(35, 139, 144, 0, 106, 192, 28, 1, 5, 0)), .Names = c("id", 
"loc", "t.arrive", "t.leave", "idle"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))


#############################################################
##Reproducible example 2 (n=100):
#############################################################
> dput(df.in)
structure(list(id = c(78, 93, 107, 84, 104, 91, 71, 66, 189, 
182, 92, 209, 96, 84, 50, 103, 182, 183, 74, 132, 101, 78, 88, 
93, 48, 107, 82, 72, 182, 83, 66, 91, 104, 50, 71, 96, 103, 74, 
182, 101, 132, 84, 78, 88, 93, 107, 83, 182, 48, 66, 96, 51, 
75, 65, 102, 80, 106, 63, 156, 51, 75, 79, 67, 65, 85, 94, 89, 
106, 69, 80, 79, 67, 69, 52, 105, 94, 73, 95, 100, 76, 55, 99, 
60, 69, 53, 86, 52, 105, 90, 64, 95, 73, 63, 100, 76, 51, 99, 
53, 75, 52), loc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("A", 
"HPB", "HPS", "B", "OPP-B", "C"), class = "factor"), t.arrive = structure(c(1425197374, 
1425197392, 1425197411, 1425197927, 1425198171, 1425198190, 1425198194, 
1425198227, 1425198303, 1425198475, 1425198812, 1425198924, 1425199119, 
1425199199, 1425199235, 1425199355, 1425199528, 1425199544, 1425199641, 
1425199643, 1425199648, 1425199801, 1425199812, 1425200087, 1425200103, 
1425200310, 1425200454, 1425200478, 1425200517, 1425200611, 1425200669, 
1425201076, 1425201105, 1425201275, 1425201287, 1425201378, 1425201536, 
1425201604, 1425201628, 1425201767, 1425201893, 1425202137, 1425202244, 
1425202255, 1425202557, 1425202566, 1425202879, 1425202962, 1425203094, 
1425203109, 1425203380, 1425196800, 1425196800, 1425197837, 1425198027, 
1425198955, 1425199074, 1425199342, 1425199465, 1425199855, 1425199929, 
1425199970, 1425200480, 1425200517, 1425200950, 1425201289, 1425201357, 
1425201879, 1425202374, 1425202982, 1425202987, 1425203318, 1425197507, 
1425198026, 1425198378, 1425198390, 1425198994, 1425199059, 1425199298, 
1425199522, 1425199528, 1425199728, 1425200115, 1425200289, 1425200373, 
1425200547, 1425200679, 1425200880, 1425200909, 1425201364, 1425201509, 
1425201801, 1425201910, 1425202039, 1425202246, 1425202490, 1425202555, 
1425202589, 1425203048, 1425203108), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), t.leave = structure(c(1425197409, 1425197531, 
1425197555, 1425197927, 1425198171, 1425198296, 1425198194, 1425198315, 
1425198411, 1425198553, 1425198818, 1425198924, 1425199119, 1425199219, 
1425199235, 1425199359, 1425199528, 1425199558, 1425199652, 1425199734, 
1425199648, 1425199801, 1425200028, 1425200198, 1425200240, 1425200364, 
1425200492, 1425200619, 1425200610, 1425200910, 1425200859, 1425201100, 
1425201302, 1425201275, 1425201467, 1425201393, 1425201569, 1425201704, 
1425201805, 1425201951, 1425202057, 1425202262, 1425202370, 1425202255, 
1425202667, 1425202840, 1425202913, 1425202990, 1425203094, 1425203109, 
1425203380, 1425196992, 1425196800, 1425197865, 1425198028, 1425198984, 
1425199149, 1425199356, 1425199466, 1425199902, 1425200051, 1425200286, 
1425200783, 1425200845, 1425201125, 1425201586, 1425201640, 1425201879, 
1425202377, 1425202986, 1425202987, 1425203318, 1425197512, 1425198026, 
1425198378, 1425198486, 1425199021, 1425199078, 1425199325, 1425199558, 
1425199810, 1425199939, 1425200118, 1425200305, 1425200485, 1425200782, 
1425200894, 1425201065, 1425201111, 1425201364, 1425201623, 1425201857, 
1425202015, 1425202039, 1425202404, 1425202671, 1425202651, 1425202834, 
1425203105, 1425203198), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    idle = c(35, 139, 144, 0, 0, 106, 0, 88, 108, 78, 6, 0, 0, 
    20, 0, 4, 0, 14, 11, 91, 0, 0, 216, 111, 137, 54, 38, 141, 
    93, 299, 190, 24, 197, 0, 180, 15, 33, 100, 177, 184, 164, 
    125, 126, 0, 110, 274, 34, 28, 0, 0, 0, 192, 0, 28, 1, 29, 
    75, 14, 1, 47, 122, 316, 303, 328, 175, 297, 283, 0, 3, 4, 
    0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 96, 27, 19, 27, 36, 282, 211, 3, 16, 112, 
    235, 215, 185, 202, 0, 114, 56, 105, 0, 158, 181, 96, 245, 
    57, 90)), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "loc", "t.arrive", 
"t.leave", "idle"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

**Here's what I'm trying to get**: take the sum of idle time contributed by each id at any given minute (has to be grouped by *loc*). Then, take the average:
[image: schematic]

**...and here's what I've tried**:

```
## Expand time into 1-min intervals
df.min <- df.in %>%
              rownames_to_column() %>%
              group_by(rowname) %>%  
              do(data.frame(min = seq(.$t.arrive, .$t.leave, by = "1 min"),
                            id = first(.$id),
                            loc = first(.$loc),
                            idle.mean = as.numeric(mean(.$idle))
              ))


## Round Off to 0 seconds to make it more tractable:
df.min$min <- as.POSIXct(round(df.min$min, "mins"))


## Calculate within each minute
df.min <- df.min %>% 
            group_by(min, loc) %>% 
            summarise(units.count = n(),
                      cum.queue.min = sum(idle.mean)/60
                      )

## Take 1 min average idle time per id
df.min <- as.data.frame(df.min)
df.min <- df.min %>%
            mutate(queue.tmean = cum.queue.min / units.count) %>%
            select(-units.count, -cum.queue.min) %>%
            arrange(min, loc)
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to whether you want the solution to "take the sum of idle time contributed by each id at any given minute (has to be grouped by loc). Then, take the average", which my solution does, or to solve according to the images you've provided, which I believe the other solutions do. They're different results, though.

Comment: I'd like the average at any given minute (grouped by loc). Obviously, the average requires a sum. In the diagram, I tried to illustrate the logic and building blocks, but it does include the average idling at any given min. The only step not illustrated was to round off to the closest min.  I did that to simplify the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be concrete, what result do you expect at `loc` = `A` at the 8:09th minute?

Comment: **If** I'm going to round `t.arrive` to the closest minute (which is what I've chosen to do), then 8:09 should not exist, and if it did, average idletime should be `NA` (not zero).

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a dataframe where each row is identified by an id-loc-time, where each time is a minute, with the value being the number of idle seconds for that time, e.g.

```
  id loc                time secs
1 46   A 2015-03-01 08:10:00   60
2 46   A 2015-03-01 08:11:00   60
3 46   A 2015-03-01 08:12:00   19
```

A simple function to create such a dataframe, given start time, idle seconds, and other identifiers:

```
library(lubridate)
make_obs <- function(start, idle, id, loc) {
  st <- round_date(start, "min")
  mins <- trunc(idle / 60)
  times <- c(st, if (mins > 0) st + minutes(1 : mins))
  data.frame(
    id = id, loc = loc, time = times, secs = c(rep(60, mins), idle %% 60)
    )
}
```

Then use `mapply` to run through the original dataset, and `dplyr` functions to aggregate:

```
library(dplyr)
out <- do.call(rbind, mapply(make_obs, 
  df.in$t.arrive, df.in$idle, df.in$id, df.in$loc,
  SIMPLIFY = FALSE))
group_by(out, loc, time) %>%
  summarise(idle = mean(secs))
```

Output:

```
Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
Groups: loc [?]

      loc                time     idle
   <fctr>              <dttm>    <dbl>
1       A 2015-03-01 08:10:00 51.66667
2       A 2015-03-01 08:11:00 60.00000
3       A 2015-03-01 08:12:00 21.50000
4       A 2015-03-01 08:23:00 30.00000
...
```

Comment: Your results don't seem to be correct. For example, if we look at `loc` = `A`, there are two `id`s whose timeframe begins in the 8:09th minute. The total seconds for that minute is 34, which leads to an average 17 (34 / 2) seconds for that time slot and location, which you don't have. Part of it may be due to the fact you're using `round_date` rather than `floor_date` (or `ceiling_date`), which causes seconds to be counted towards minutes inconsistently.

Comment: My results are consistent with OP's own calculations, though.  I do agree that using `floor` or `ceiling` may be more consistent than `round`; but I wrote my answer such that it returns OP's desired results.

Comment: Thanks! This approach works, but it's very, very slow on a large dataframe of 500,000 observations.

Comment: Re. using `floor_date` (or `ceiling_date`): I'd argue it leads to increased consistency at the expense of accuracy: `> floor(3.999)
[1] 3
> round(3.999)
[1] 4`

Answer (score 2):

### data.table approach

Very efficient `data.table` approach with no loops

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
setDT(dt.in)
dt.in[, arrive_min := round_date(t.arrive, "mins")]
dt2 <- dt.in[, .(mins = arrive_min + (0:floor(idle/60))*60) , by = .(id, loc, arrive_min)]
```

This summarization assumes unique `arrive_min` for each grouping variables, which is automatically satisfied by adding `arrive_min` to the grouping variables. (See the erratic example below. Earlier solution throws `differing rows` error due to non-uniqueness of `arrive_min`). Once we get these sorted out, the rest is pretty straightforward

```
dt.in[, mins:=arrive_min, ]
dt_full <- dt.in[dt2, on = c("id", "loc", "mins")]
dt_full[, .(mins = mins, idle=c(rep(60, idle[1]/60), idle[1]%%60)), by = .(id, loc, i.arrive_min)
   ][, .(ave_idle=mean(idle)), by = .(mins, loc)]


#                   min1 loc ave_idle
# 1: 2015-03-01 08:10:00   A 51.66667
# 2: 2015-03-01 08:11:00   A 60.00000
# 3: 2015-03-01 08:12:00   A 21.50000
# 4: 2015-03-01 08:23:00   A 30.00000
# 5: 2015-03-01 08:24:00   A 46.00000
# 6: 2015-03-01 08:00:00   B 60.00000
# 7: 2015-03-01 08:01:00   B 60.00000
# 8: 2015-03-01 08:02:00   B 60.00000
# 9: 2015-03-01 08:03:00   B 12.00000
#10: 2015-03-01 08:17:00   B 28.00000
#11: 2015-03-01 08:20:00   B  1.00000
#12: 2015-03-01 08:12:00   C  5.00000
#13: 2015-03-01 08:20:00   C  0.00000
```

**Note** that, in creating `mins = arrive_min + (0:floor(idle/60))*60` and `idle=c(rep(60, idle[1]/60), idle[1]%%60)`, we assume that for each grouping variables (`id`, `loc`, `arrive_min`), there is unique `idle`. The former converts `t.arrive=08:01:00,  idle=159` to `mins=c(08:01:00, 08:02:00, 08:03:00)`, and the latter converts `c(159, NA , NA)` to `c(60, 60, 39)`. So, this method should be modified if you have a data points like:

```
  id loc            t.arrive             t.leave    idle
1 78   A 2015-03-01 08:09:36 2015-03-01 08:09:58      22
2 78   A 2015-03-01 08:09:34 2015-03-01 08:10:09      35
```

---

### dplyr

We might as well use `dplyr`.
`do` operations are little clumsy compared to the `data.table` counterpart.

```
df.in <- df.in %>% 
  mutate(arrive_min=round_date(t.arrive, "mins"))
df2 <- df.in %>% 
  group_by(id, loc, arrive_min) %>% 
  do(data.frame(id=.$id, loc=.$loc, mins = .$arrive_min + (0:floor(.$idle/60))*60))
df.in$mins <- df.in$arrive_min
left_join(df2, df.in, by=c("id", "loc", "mins")) %>%  
  group_by(id, loc, arrive_min.x) %>% 
  do(data.frame(min1=.$mins, idle=c(rep(60, .$idle[1]/60), .$idle[1]%%60))) %>% 
  group_by(min1, loc) %>% 
  summarise(ave_idle=mean(idle)) 


#                  min1  loc.x ave_idle
#                <dttm> <fctr>    <dbl>
#1  2015-03-01 08:00:00      B 60.00000
#2  2015-03-01 08:01:00      B 60.00000
#3  2015-03-01 08:02:00      B 60.00000
#4  2015-03-01 08:03:00      B 12.00000
#5  2015-03-01 08:10:00      A 51.66667
#6  2015-03-01 08:11:00      A 60.00000
#7  2015-03-01 08:12:00      A 21.50000
#8  2015-03-01 08:12:00      C  5.00000
#9  2015-03-01 08:17:00      B 28.00000
#10 2015-03-01 08:20:00      B  1.00000
#11 2015-03-01 08:20:00      C  0.00000
#12 2015-03-01 08:23:00      A 30.00000
#13 2015-03-01 08:24:00      A 46.00000
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd like to be leveraging the efficiency of data.table (though I'm not experienced with it), because my data is large.  This throws many errors on the full data. `dt2 <- df.in[, .(min1 = min1 + (0:floor(idle/60))*60) , by = .(id, loc)]` gives: `Warning messages:
1: In 0:floor(idle/60) :
  numerical expression has 1608 elements: only the first used` and `12: In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Similar kind of error: `+   do(data.frame(id=.$id, loc=.$loc, min1 = .$min1 + (0:floor(.$idle/60))*60))
Error in data.frame(id = .$id, loc = .$loc, min1 = .$min1 + (0:floor(.$idle/60)) *  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 11
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In 0:floor(.$idle/60) :
  numerical expression has 1507 elements: only the first used
2: In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Comment: Can you provide an instance of dataset for which the the error is reproducible?

Comment: @ThomasSpeidel I've updated the solution. Hope that source of the error  is more transparent now.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
# Create sequence of datetimes by second from t.arrive to t.leave for each observation
df <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df.in)) {
    df <- bind_rows(
        df,
        slice(data_frame(  # slice cuts off last second entry
            t.present = seq(df.in[[i, 't.arrive']], df.in[[i, 't.leave']], by = 'sec'),
            id = df.in[[i, 'id']],
            loc = df.in[[i, 'loc']]), -n()))
}

# Calculate target metric
df$t.present.min <- as.POSIXct(trunc(df$t.present, 'mins'))
result <- df %>%
    group_by(id, loc, t.present.min) %>%
    summarise(secs.present = n()) %>%
    group_by(loc, t.present.min) %>%
    summarise(avg.secs = mean(secs.present))
result
```

Result:

```
      loc       t.present.min avg.secs
   <fctr>              <dttm>    <dbl>
1       A 2015-03-01 08:09:00 17.00000
2       A 2015-03-01 08:10:00 39.33333
3       A 2015-03-01 08:11:00 60.00000
4       A 2015-03-01 08:12:00 23.00000
5       A 2015-03-01 08:23:00 50.00000
6       A 2015-03-01 08:24:00 56.00000
7       B 2015-03-01 08:00:00 60.00000
8       B 2015-03-01 08:01:00 60.00000
9       B 2015-03-01 08:02:00 60.00000
10      B 2015-03-01 08:03:00 12.00000
11      B 2015-03-01 08:17:00 28.00000
12      B 2015-03-01 08:20:00  1.00000
13      C 2015-03-01 08:11:00  5.00000
```